# In Rust, what is `fn() -> ()`?

Tags: function, rust, traits

I have a grasp of the Fn (capital-F) traits: `Fn`, `FnMut`, `FnOnce`. I understand that they are traits and work like traits.

But what about `fn` (lowercase-f)? It gets a different coloring in editors, which tells me it's not a trait. It can also be used in some places where the others can't (and vice-versa), though it seems to behave similarly in other cases. I couldn't find anything explaining it directly in the docs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rust has three kinds of function-like types:

1. [**Function items**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html) are what you get when you create a function by using `fn foo() {...}`. It's also the type of the constructor of a tuple-like struct or enum variant. Function items are zero-sized (they contain no data), and every non-generic function has a unique, unnameable function item type. In error messages, the compiler displays these "Voldemort types" as something like `fn() -> () {foo}` (with the name of the function in `{}`).
2. [**Closures**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html) are values similar to function items, but closures may contain data: copies of or references to whatever variables they capture from their environment. As you already know, you create a closure by using closure syntax (`|args| expression`). Like function items, closures have unique, unnameable types (rendered by the compiler something like `[closure@src/main.rs:4:11: 4:23]`).
3. [**Function pointers**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html) are what you're asking about: the types that look like `fn() -> ()`. Function pointers cannot contain data, but they are not zero-sized; as their name suggests, they are pointers. A function pointer may point either to a function item, or to a closure that captures nothing, but it cannot be null.

Function items and closures are automatically coerced to the relevant function pointer type when possible, so that's why `let f: fn(i32) = |_| ();` works: because the closure captures nothing, it can be coerced to a function pointer.

All three function-like types implement the relevant `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` traits (except that closures might not implement `Fn` or `FnMut` depending on what they capture). Function items and function pointers also implement `Copy`, `Clone`, `Send` and `Sync` (closures only implement these traits when all their contents do).

Performance-wise, function pointers are something of a compromise between generics and trait objects. They have to be dereferenced to be called, so calling a function pointer may be slower than calling a function item or closure directly, but still faster than calling a `dyn Fn` trait object, which involves a vtable lookup in addition to the indirect call. However, in real code there are many variables that confound naive analysis; if the difference in performance is important to you, you should measure it instead of guessing which is faster.

#### References

- [What's the practical difference between fn item and fn pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438613/whats-the-practical-difference-between-fn-item-and-fn-pointer)
- [Why design a language with unique anonymous types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172736/why-design-a-language-with-unique-anonymous-types)
- [How do I make a struct for FFI that contains a nullable function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572985/how-do-i-make-a-struct-for-ffi-that-contains-a-nullable-function-pointer)
- [Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696907/why-does-passing-a-closure-to-function-which-accepts-a-function-pointer-not-work)

Answer (score 4):

It is a [function pointer type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html).

It refers **only** to a function, not a closure, since it contains just the address of the function not the captured environment a closure needs.

A `Fn` trait (capital F) can refer either to a closure or a function.

Comment: I am able to cast a closure to `fn`. Although, maybe that implicitly forbids it from capturing anything.

Comment: @brundolf you guessed it right, a closure that does not capture anything is actually a function.

Answer (score 1):

fn is the type for a function pointer. See also here in the documentation:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html