# What's the practical difference between fn item and fn pointer?

Tags: rust, callback, function-pointers

```
fn func(_: i64) -> bool {
    true
}

fn func_of_func(callback: &fn(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool {
    (*callback)(arg)
}

fn main() {
    let is_positive = &func;
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:33
  |
9 |     println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
  |
  = note: expected reference `&fn(i64) -> bool`
             found reference `&fn(i64) -> bool {func}`
```

Why does this error occur while I have passed a pointer, not `fn`? I want to know the practical difference between using `fn` and pointer to `fn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fn(i64) -> bool` is [already a function pointer](/q/64298245/3650362), so `&fn(i64) -> bool` is a reference to a function pointer. Since function pointers are `Copy`, you should never have any reason to write this.

If you're writing a function that takes something function-like as an argument, you should usually use generics (or `impl Fn`, as in [Mike Graham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64439335/3650362), which means the same thing):

```
fn func_of_func<F: FnOnce(i64) -> bool>(callback: F, arg: i64) -> bool {
    callback(arg)
}
```

This means that when you call `func_of_func` with a function item such as `func`, `callback` will be compiled to a direct function call instead of a function pointer, which is easier for the compiler to optimize.

If the function cannot be made generic (perhaps because it's a member of an object safe trait), you should usually use trait objects instead, which allows the caller to pass a closure:

```
fn func_of_func(callback: &dyn Fn(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool { ... }
fn func_of_func(callback: &mut dyn FnMut(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool { ... }
// using `FnOnce` requires boxing
fn func_of_func(callback: Box<dyn FnOnce(i64) -> bool>, arg: i64) -> bool { ... }
```

Function pointers should only be used when the function definitely cannot capture anything. They are mostly useful for FFI with C, and as type parameters to `PhantomData` in generic structs.

#### References

- [In Rust, what is `fn() -> ()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298245/in-rust-what-is-fn)

Comment: As for " a direct function call instead of a function pointer, which is easier for the compiler to optimize", what kind of optimization would a compiler do here?

Comment: @ZeGao [Inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) the function call in `callback(arg)` is trivial when `callback` is a statically known function, but nigh-impossible when `callback` is a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this with

```
fn func_of_func(callback: &fn(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool {
    (*callback)(arg)
}

fn main() {
    let is_positive = func;
    println!("{}", func_of_func(&is_positive, 8));
    println!("{}", func_of_func(&is_positive, 8));
}
```

Or more straightforwardly by not adding a level of indirection

```
fn func_of_func(callback: fn(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool {
    callback(arg)
}

fn main() {
    let is_positive = func;
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
}
```

---

It's more common to use `Fn` traits, which have the benefit of allowing closures as well as functions

```
fn func(x: i64) -> bool {
    true
}
    
fn func_of_func(callback: impl FnOnce(i64) -> bool, arg: i64) -> bool {
    callback(arg)
}

fn main() {
    let is_positive = func;
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
    println!("{}", func_of_func(is_positive, 8));
}
```