# Why accept `fn(..)` instead of `Fn(...)` in generics in Rust?

Tags: assembly, optimization, rust, closures

Why accept `fn(..)` instead of `Fn(...)` in generics in Rust?

My intuition is that

- on one hand if code accepts closure with context -> `Fn()`, but we provide "no context" closure `fn(...)` then compiler should optimize for `fn(...)`.
- on the other hand, maybe there are advantages on actual memory and assembly representation of `fn(...)` (e.g. takes less space, due to no need to store context), that would make us prefer to restrict our generic type to accept `fn(...)` types not `Fn(...) types ?

Therefore:

- When one may want to restrict type to `fn(...)` in generic types?
- When it brings difference,
- and what kind of difference?

Below some pseudocodes for inspiration, feel free to polish them , this is not limited to those cases, as maybe memory size difference is better to demonstrate with `Vec<dyn fn(X)->Y>` vs `Vec<Fn(X)->Y>` (or using `unboxed_closures` syntax ;) ).

Sketches, examples, but not limited to those:

```rust
// peusdo code
pub struct Foo <F,X,Y>
where
F: fn(X)->Y ,
...
{
    fx: F,
}

impl Foo<F,X,Y> where
F: fn(X)->Y,
...
{
    pub fn new(foo: F) -> Self;
    ...
}

// peusdo code
pub struct FooByRef <'a,X,Y>
where
F: &'a dyn fn(X)->Y ,
...
{
    fx: F,
}

impl Foo<'a,X,Y> where
F: &'a dyn fn(X)->Y,
...
{
    pub fn new(foo: &'a dyn fn(X)->Y) -> Self;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `fn(T)->U` is not a trait, but a concrete type. Given that, your examples not only fail to compile, but don't really make sense.

Comment: Is this just about which is technically faster? I think the best answer to that question is: function pointers (`fn`) should theoretically be at least as fast as the `Fn` trait. However, definitely go with the `Fn` trait 99% of the time since it lets you use closures, and I would imagine that the performance is nearly identical after optimizations.

Comment: Thank you, both above answers are insightful despite just comments :)

Comment: There is no reason to assume function pointers are faster than generics. The compiler monomorphizes generics for every concrete type that is actually used, so there is no overhead. You only get overhead when using dynamic dispatch, i.e. `Box<dyn Fn(T) -> U>` or similar.

Comment: I started summarizing comments in answer below, which is set to be "community wiki"  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67786735/544721

Comment: This question seems unfocused, and as pointed out already the code examples don't make sense. I wrote an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298245/in-rust-what-is-fn which may help you understand better what's up with all these function types.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of how `fn()` and `Fn()` can be used in structs.

```rs
struct Foo<F>
// there is no need for trait bounds in a struct definition
{
  function: F,
}

// the impementation is generic over a generic type `F`, hence `impl<F> Foo<F>`
// `impl Foo<F>` would be an implementation for a concrete type called `F`
impl<F> Foo<F>
where F: Fn()
{
  fn new(function: F) -> Self {
    Self { function } // equivalent to `Foo { function: function }`
  }
  fn call_function(&self) {
    (self.function)();
  }
}
```

`Foo` requires a specific type which implements `Fn()` in order to be used.
This makes `Foo` restricted to the single specific type,
be it `fn()` or the type of one concrete closure or function.
The restriction, however, makes it possible to store only the context of `F`
since the implementation can be inferred from the type.

```rs
struct Bar {
  function: fn(),
}

impl Bar {
  fn new(function: fn()) -> Self {
    Self { function }
  }
  fn call_function(&self) {
    (self.function)()
  }
}
```

`Bar` is equivalent to `Foo<fn()>`, the only thing stored in it is the function pointer. It is restricted to functions and closures with no context, which can be cast to `fn()`.

```rs
struct DynRefFoo<'a> {
  function: &'a dyn Fn(),
}

impl<'a> DynRefFoo<'a> {
  fn new(function: &'a dyn Fn()) -> Self {
    Self { function }
  }
  fn call_function(&self) {
    (self.function)();
  }
}
```

`DynRefFoo` may contain references to multiple types across its instances.
For this reason, pointers to both the context and the implementation of the `Fn()` trait have to be stored in the struct.

In terms of the `Fn` trait, the context of `fn` is the pointer and the implementation simply calls the function behind the pointer.

Additionally, each function has its own zero-sized type which implements `Fn` so there is a slight difference between using a concrete function and a pointer to that function as `dyn Fn`.

To sum up:

- `dyn Fn` works for everything.
- `fn` can store functions and no-context closures only.
- `Fn` bounded generic types are limited to a single closure since each closure has its own type.

Answer (score 0):

- `fn` is concrete type as it has defined signature
- `Fn` is trait - it has not fully defined/concrete signature, as it may change depending on captured context, what is resolved on use by compiler
- `fn` is function pointer, so it consumes `usize::BITS` of memory
- "There is no reason to assume function pointers are faster than generics. The compiler monomorphizes generics for every concrete type that is actually used, so there is no overhead. You only get overhead when using dynamic dispatch, i.e. Box<dyn Fn(T) -> U> or similar"