# Cast to inferred function type in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

Let's say we have a type `FARPROC` that we receive as result of certain *Win32* operations, such as `GetProcAddress`. It's definition is as follows:

```rust
pub type FARPROC = unsafe extern "system" fn() -> isize;
```

This type then needs to be converted to a valid function type so we can call it. As developers, we know the function signature (from documentation), but we need to pass that knowledge onto the compiler. A straightforward approach is to use `transmute` with explicit function type as following:

```rust
let address: FARPROC = unsafe { GetProcAddress(module, proc).unwrap() };
let function: extern "system" fn(i32) = unsafe { transmute (&address) };
```

But what if we wanted to *infer* the function type from one of the existing functions that we defined in our rust code? Let's say we have some function with lengthy definition:

```rust
pub fn foo(arg1: i32, arg2: c_void, arg3: *const c_char) {
   // snip
}
```

In order to keep our code DRY, is it possible to use that function type with `transmute`?

My attempted solution looks like the following snippet:

```rust
pub fn cast_to_function<F>(address: FARPROC, _fn: &F) -> F {
    unsafe { transmute_copy(&address) }
}

/// Usage

let address: FARPROC = unsafe { GetProcAddress(module, proc).unwrap() };
let function = cast_to_function(address, &foo);
function(1, ...);
```

This attempted solution is based on the similar C++ code that is working:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T FnCast(void* fnToCast, T pFnCastTo) {
    return (T)fnToCast;
}

/// Usage

void bar(int arg1, void* arg2, const char* arg3){
   // snip
}

auto address = (void*) GetProcAddress(...); 
auto function = FnCast(address, &bar);
function(1, address, "bar");
```

The problem with my attempted solution in rust is that `cast_to_function` always returns the function with address that points to the referenced function, rather than an address that points to the one which we provided. Hence, given what was laid out so far, is it possible to intelligently infer the function type from its definition and cast arbitrary type to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why your attempted solution doesn't work, we must know about the different kinds of function types in Rust; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64298764/4087571). When you make this call:

```rust
let function = cast_to_function(address, &foo);
```

the argument `&foo` is a reference to the specific function item `foo`; it is not a function pointer like `address`. Due to the type signature of `cast_to_function()`, this means the return type `T` is that same function item. Function items are zero-sized types, so the `transmute_copy()` inside `cast_to_function()` doesn't do anything.

The simplest solution is to cast `foo` to a function pointer before calling `cast_to_function()`:

```rust
let function = cast_to_function(address, foo as fn(_, _));
```

(you'll also need to change `cast_to_function()`'s signature to take `_fn` by value: `_fn: F`).

This is still a bit of boilerplate with the manual casting, though as demonstrated you can use placeholders (`_`) instead of writing out each argument type. If you get the number of arguments wrong you just get a compile error (you can't accidentally cast `foo` to a wrong signature).

---

Getting rid of the required casting in the caller code is more complicated. I came up with this solution, which uses a trait to do the casting, and uses a macro to write the impls for functions of varying arity:

```rust
/// Casts a function pointer to a new function pointer, with the new type derived from a
/// template function.
///
/// SAFETY:
/// - `f` must be a function pointer (e.g. `fn(i32) -> i32`)
/// - `template`'s type must be a valid function signature for `f`
unsafe fn fn_ptr_cast<T, U, V>(fn_ptr: T, _template_fn: U) -> V
where
    T: Copy + 'static,
    U: FnPtrCast<V>,
{
    debug_assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<T>(), mem::size_of::<usize>());

    U::fn_ptr_cast(fn_ptr)
}

unsafe trait FnPtrCast<U> {
    unsafe fn fn_ptr_cast<T>(fn_ptr: T) -> U;
}

macro_rules! impl_fn_cast {
    ( $($arg:ident),* ) => {
        unsafe impl<Fun, Out, $($arg),*> FnPtrCast<fn($($arg),*) -> Out> for Fun
        where
            Fun: Fn($($arg),*) -> Out,
        {
            unsafe fn fn_ptr_cast<T>(fn_ptr: T) -> fn($($arg),*) -> Out {
                ::std::mem::transmute(::std::ptr::read(&fn_ptr as *const T as *const *const T))
            }
        }
    }
}

impl_fn_cast!();
impl_fn_cast!(A);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C, D);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C, D, E);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C, D, E, F);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G);
impl_fn_cast!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H);
```

This lets you do

```rust
let function = fn_ptr_cast(address, foo);
```

without any manual casting.

Note: This last solution assumes function pointers and data pointers are the same size, which may not always be the case on some platforms.